# how to build a matrix or a table

Tags: r

I have 4 small dfs that I want to use to build a table/df. I tried to input the values into a matrix first, then convert it to df. however my codes do not work. And I feel my way might not be a good way. Could anyone guide me on this? maybe how to build the correct matrix first, and then maybe other better way to do this task? Many thanks.

Data

```
T1<- structure(list(AESERYN = structure(c(1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), pt_sae = c(12L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

T2<- structure(list(AESERYN = structure(1:2, .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    pt_sae = c(9, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

T3<- structure(list(AESERYN = structure(c(1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), sae = c("62", "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

T4<-structure(list(AESERYN = structure(1:2, .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    sae = c("22", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Building new df( not working):

```
test<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(unlist(T3[,"sae"]),
                              unlist(T4[,"sae"]),
                              unlist(T1[,"pt_sae"]),
                              unlist(T2[,"pt_sae"])),
                  ncol = 4, byrow = FALSE, 
                  dimnames = list(c("Non-Serious AE", 
                                    "Serious AE",
                                    "Unkonwn"),
                                  c("T3","T4","T1","T2"))))
```

The outcome should looks like this:

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Good catch. Just updated the post. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to get all the 'T' objects in a `list`, then bind the `list` elements with `bind_rows`, replace the 'Y', 'N', `NA` values with the 'Serious AE', 'Non-Serious AE' and 'Unknown', reshape from 'long' to 'wide' with`pivot_wider`, and convert to `matrix` after converting the first column as row names

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)
library(janitor)
mget(paste0("T", 1:4)) %>% 
   bind_rows(.id = 'grp') %>%
    transmute(grp, grp2 = fct_recode(replace_na(as.character(AESERYN), 
      "Unknown"),  `Non-Serious AE` = "N", 'Serious AE' = "Y"),
       value = coalesce(pt_sae, as.numeric(sae))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = value, values_fill = 0) %>% 
    column_to_rownames('grp2') %>% 
    as.matrix
```

-output

```
               T1 T2 T3 T4
Non-Serious AE 12  9 62 22
Serious AE      1  0  1  0
Unknown         1  0  1  0
```

Comment: @Stataq can you post as a new question as the comment is not clear

Comment: When I run the codes, I got following error message `Error in values_fill[[value]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: @Stataq is it based on the same example or different.  If it is the same, can you change `values_fill = list(value = 0)` (probably due to `tidyr` version)

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
mylist = list(T1 = T1, T2 = T2, T3 = T3, T4 = T4)

mylist %>%
  imap( ~set_names(.x, c(names(.x)[1], .y))) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by='AESERYN') %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(AESERYN = recode(AESERYN,  
                    N = 'Non-Serious', Y = 'Serious', .missing = 'Unknown'),
         across(T1:T4, ~coalesce(.x, 0)))%>%
  column_to_rownames('AESERYN')

            T1 T2 T3 T4
Non-Serious 12  9 62 22
Serious      1  0  1  0
Unknown      1  0  1  0
```

NOte that you can use the code `mget(paste0('T', 1:4)` as indicated by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867762/how-to-build-a-matrix-or-a-table/68867911#68867911)

Answer (score 1):

This can be generalized a bit, but in a nutshell:

```
cols <- c("Non-Serious AE", "Serious AE", "Unkonwn")

T1$group <- cols
T2$group <- cols[1:2]
T3$group <- cols
T4$group <- cols[1:2]

xy <- Reduce(f = function(x, y) merge(x, y, sort = FALSE, by = "group", all = TRUE),
       list(T3[, c("sae", "group")],
            T4[, c("sae", "group")], 
            T1[, c("pt_sae", "group")], 
            T2[, c("pt_sae", "group")]
       )
)

rownames(xy) <- xy$group
xy$group <- NULL
colnames(xy) <- c("T3", "T4", "T1", "T2")
xy[is.na(xy)] <- 0
xy

               T3 T4 T1 T2
Non-Serious AE 62 22 12  9
Serious AE      1  0  1  0
Unkonwn         1  0  1  0
```